# Time series from a DataFrame in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, x-axis

I am developing an application which is to graph values from a DataFrame using PyQtGraph.

The issues I am having have to do with the custom X-axis, which is to display the selected interval from the TimeStamp in the dataframe with the exact dateTime. I have used a modified `DateAxisItem` class that sets the `tickValues` and `tickStrings` for the X-axis 
`date_axis = DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')`:

```
def tickValues(self, minVal, maxVal, size):
        
  maxMajSteps = int(size/self._pxLabelWidth)

        dt1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(minVal)
        dt2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(maxVal)

        dx = maxVal - minVal
        majticks = []

        if dx > 63072001:  # 3600s*24*(365+366) = 2 years (count leap year)
            d = timedelta(days=366)
            for y in range(dt1.year + 1, dt2.year):
                dt = datetime(year=y, month=1, day=1)
                majticks.append(mktime(dt.timetuple()))

        elif dx > 5270400:  # 3600s*24*61 = 61 days
            d = timedelta(days=31)
            dt = dt1.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0,
                             second=0, microsecond=0) + d
            while dt < dt2:
                # make sure that we are on day 1 (even if always sum 31 days)
                dt = dt.replace(day=1)
                majticks.append(mktime(dt.timetuple()))
                dt += d
...
```

```
def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        """Reimplemented from PlotItem to adjust to the range"""
        ret = []
        if not values:
            return []

        if spacing >= 31622400:  # 366 days
            fmt = "%Y"

        elif spacing >= 2678400:  # 31 days
            fmt = "%Y %b"

        elif spacing >= 86400:  # = 1 day
            fmt = "%b/%d"

        elif spacing >= 3600:  # 1 h
            fmt = "%b/%d-%Hh"
...
```

To graph the interval I am taking the total seconds for the specific values as such:

`interval = (df.TimeStamp - df.TimeStamp.min()).dt.total_seconds()`

I followed the guide and set the plot as:

`date_axis.attachToPlotItem(self.graphWidget.getPlotItem())` 
`self.graphWidget.plot(x=interval, y=graphed_variable)`

The graph itself is generated correctly, however the X-axis, does not show the correct TimeStamp and reverts to default such as 1/Jan/1h. I suspect this is a result of using a Series, instead of actual dateTime.

Is there a better way to implement a proper DateTime X-axis from the dataframe, or am I mishandling the class?

I have read other similar questions, but can not seem to find an answer.

Edit: I have done some retrospective and the dates are not displayed due to the `x=interval` being of type float64. Ideally I would like to just have `x=df.TimeStamp` since it contains all the timestamps in datetime64 format. However i get the error \

```
in boundingRect
self._boundingRect = QtCore.QRectF(xmn-px, ymn-py, (2*px)+xmx-xmn, (2*py)+ymx-ymn)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncBinaryResolutionError: ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, and not rely on external resources for code (they may become unavailable and then make the question invalid), especially if using repositories that could change their contents and even more if you *modified* that code. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date in tickStrings however you like. In this instance from pd.TimeStamp to python datetime and then to string using the specified format.

```
def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
    '''
    determine fmt based on spacing
    '''

    return [pd.to_datetime(df.Date[value]).strftime(fmt) for value in values if max(values) > 0]
```